# flutter update the ui when the data changes from another page

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom navigation bar that has 2 pages..

Page 1-- display a list of items that a user can add to their favorite list which is then save in the db

Page 2: displays the favorite list - so in the init state , I read the DB and show the data..

The above works the first time

However, page 2 is not updated, if the user and favorite an item in page 1  and then go to page 2 .

The issue is the initstate is only called the first time

How do I force a refresh when I go to page 2

I am using the provider  pattern   -ChangeNotifier

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Bloc pattern or any other pattern to deal with state ? if not, you should be

Comment: A good way would be to use bloc pattern. Wrap page 2's widget with a streambuilder and then in page 1 you can interact with the stream sending data to it causing page 2 to refresh. Check [this](https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1)

Comment: show more code... this can work with the provider pattern - ChangeNotifier

Answer (score 1):

I recommender use a Streams to observer the change of data.

This is a link when you can learn a little of streams in flutters:

https://medium.com/flutterpub/exploring-streams-in-flutter-4732e5524dd8

https://dev.to/nitishk72/understanding-streams-in-flutter-dart-2pb8